# How can I find a Panel object in a Form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a task to generate a XML file of the layout, but I seem to have a problem recognizing Panel controls on the form. To recognize the objects, I use something like this:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    if (c is Button) {
        //generate XML...
    } else if (c is Panel) {
        //generate XML...
    }
}
```

It finds all the controls just fine, but not the Panel objects.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Is panel not a Control?

Comment: you may have to go through recursively.

Comment: Yes, windows forms. Recursively, how?

Comment: Panel holds other controls so you may have to Check if there is a Child control.. how many panels are you using..?

Comment: Well, in this Form just one.

Comment: Try stepping thru the code based on your code you have an IfElse statement but now code to execute once the conditional statement has been true ..please provide more code.. the code you posted works but where is the rest of your code..? ALSO Paste the full Method and OR EVENT HANDLER where you are expecting this code to work..

Comment: Try to create a smaller project that uses the same code bug just has a panel on the form and debug in this minimized scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A panel *is* a Control, but you only get the Controls which are directly in the Form, not the ones that are inside other Controls.

So how about something like this:

```
void DoRecursive(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control subCtrl in ctrl.Controls) DoRecursive(subCtrl);

    if (ctrl is Button) etc.
}
```

Or perhaps your `//generate XML...` as a Button exits the `foreach`. Perhaps it has a `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this recursive function .

```
var panels = FindControls<Panel>(aForm).ToList();

IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(Control ctrl) where T: Control
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(T)) yield return (T)c;
        foreach (var subC in FindControls<T>(c))
            yield return subC;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a simple form having one button  and one panel on the form and one button inside the panel. It worked for me finding the first button and the panel. 
Maybe the problem is you want to access the controls whose parent is the panel?

Comment: Well, damn. I have a Panel, and a Button inside it, but it won't find the Button neither the Panel.

Comment: Is it found when you use `else if (c is ScrollableControl)`?

Comment: I found that if I put the button in the panel, it didn't find the button while outside the panel it did, but in both cases it found the panel fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work. Try modifying the code to not do an `else if` and see if you can locate the Panel:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    if (c is Panel) {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, I found the " + c.Name + " panel!");
    }
}
```

We could also try locating it by name and seeing what type of a control it is:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    // Looks for a control called 'panel1' - put in your panel's name
    if (c.Name == "panel1") {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, I found a " + c.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thats the problem basically. If i put it this way, it won't show the MessageBox either.

Comment: What happens if you put this code right after the `InitializeComponent()` method that starts that window?

Comment: @JaredHarley The only way changing the `else if` to an `if` would help is if you had a control that was both a `Button` and a `Panel`.  That's...not possible.

Comment: @Servy I know, but I wanted to make sure that his loop wasn't exiting early for some other reason, since what we were shown was some simplified code.